# How can I convert an hstore[] column to jsonb?

Tags: postgresql, hstore, jsonb

I have an `hstore[]` column that I want to convert to `jsonb`, but it seems that I cannot cast between the two types. (I *can* cast from plain `hstore` without issue).

For example, if I had `'{foo=>bar,baz=>quux}'::hstore[]` in a cell, I would want it to be converted to `'[{"foo":"bar","baz":"quux"}]'::jsonb`.

How can this be accomplished in postgresql?

Comment: Isn't your `hstore[]` just a `hstore(text[])`? Did you try with `hstore_to_json_loose(hstore)` and then converting to `jsonb`?

Comment: Please note that your example makes little sense, the targeted `jsonb` response could be generated from `'{"foo=>bar,baz=>quux"}'::hstore[]` instead. Your original example `'{foo=>bar,baz=>quux}'::hstore[]` could be transformed into `'[{"foo":"bar"},{"baz":"quux"}]'::jsonb` instead (the `,` character is a separator in both the array and the `hstore` types -- see [array inputs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you could use the `USING` clause of the [`ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) for conversions with extra logic (or for conversions, which has no explicit casts between their types).

The expression for `SELECT`ing the transformed value is:

```
select (select json_agg(hstore_to_json(h)) from unnest(hstore_array) h)::jsonb
from   table_name
```

(Or, you could use [`hstore_to_json_loose(h)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) to get numbers & booleans instead of always getting strings.)

Unfortunately, you cannot use subselects in this `USING` clause , so you can do either:

1. create a temporary function & use that in `USING`

   ```
   create function temp_hstore_array_to_jsonb(hstore[])
     returns jsonb
     language sql
     immutable
   as $func$
     select json_agg(hstore_to_json(h))::jsonb
     from   unnest($1) h
   $func$;

   alter table table_name
     alter column hstore_array
     type jsonb
     using temp_hstore_array_to_jsonb(hstore_array);

   drop function temp_hstore_array_to_jsonb(hstore[]);

   -- optionally rename column
   ```
2. create another column, copy converted data & delete the original column

   ```
   alter table table_name
     add column jsonb_copy jsonb;

   update table_name
   set    jsonb_copy = (select json_agg(hstore_to_json(h))
                        from   unnest(hstore_array) h)::jsonb;

   alter table table_name drop column hstore_array;

   -- optionally rename column back like the dropped one
   ```

   But this later one has a weakness: the old column (to be dropped) might have dependent objects, which can make it harder to actually drop (`CASCADE` will drop them too, but that might not be what you want).